# Paypal bug: why does it not pick up the shipping value from the shipping variable?

Tags: php, paypal

Why paypal does not pick up the shipping value from these variables form,

```
<input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="<?php echo number_format($cost_shipping,2); ?>">
```

or

```
<input type="hidden" name="shipping_1" value="<?php echo number_format($cost_shipping,2); ?>">
```

or

```
<input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="<?php echo number_format($cost_shipping,2); ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="shipping2" value="<?php echo number_format($cost_shipping,2); ?>">
```

the `postage and handling` always show `0.00` on the paypal sandbox unless I use `handling_cart` variable,

```
<input type="hidden" name="handling_cart" value="<?php echo number_format($cost_shipping,2); ?>">
```

Something wrong with the paypal sandbox??

Comment: What value are you using for `cmd`?

Comment: `shipping_1` should work fine with that. Are you certain it doesn't work for you? See also the example at https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_cart_upload -- and ensure that "Allow transaction-based shipping values to override shipping calculator" (or similar wording) is ticked in Profile > Shipping Calculator.